# Alternative for window load for JqMobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, window-load

Is their any alternative for window load event for jquery mobile..??

```
$(window).load(function(){
// Code Here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into the jQM Documentation for specific page loading events as there could be a couple that would work for you depending on what functionality, callbacks, etc...

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html

I would think you're looking for `pagechange`

> This event is triggered after the `changePage()` request has finished
>   loading the page into the DOM and all page transition animations have
>   completed. Note that any pageshow or pagehide events will have fired
>   *BEFORE* this event is triggered. Callbacks for this particular event will be passed a data object as the 2nd arg. The properties for this
>   object are as follows:
>
> - *toPage* (object or string) This property represents the page the    caller wishes to make active. It can be either a jQuery collection
>     object containing the page DOM element, or an absolute/relative url
>     to an internal or external page. The value exactly matches the 1st
>     arg to the changePage() call that triggered the event.
> - *options* (object) This object contains the configuration options to be    used for the current changePage() call.

Also I would read the `methods` page as well

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/methods.html